# SSH but not ping

Tags: ssh, embedded-linux, wget

I have an Ubuntu VM (running on MacOS host) and am trying to connect to another box that is running Linux (busybox, IIRC).

I can ssh from machine A (Ubuntu-VM) to machine B (busybox).  I can ping from A -> B, but I cannot ping from B -> A.

Machine A has IP of 10.0.2.15, B has IP of 10.1.10.216.

My ultimate goal is to be able to use wget on B to get files from A, and I'm hoping that solving this ping problem will allow B to see A and allow magic to occur.

My network comprehension is near zero, so this is probably trivial, but any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't give any details about how the networks are connected, but I am assuming that you are using VirtualBox and you have the adapter set as NAT (Because that 10.0.2.15 is the default NAT ip for VB), is that right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: And the computer B is another VM or is a computer in the network of the MacOS host?

Comment: Computer B is another computer running busybox linux,  The IP of the Host (MacOS) is 10.1.10.97.  B can ping Host.

Comment: I replied to your question in the best manner I could, but I think this is off-topic, should be posted in superuser.com as it is not a programming question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a NAT interface, Virtualbox will mask all the traffic from your virtual machine to the outside network using the IP address of the host. To clarify this, the traffic that is arriving to computer B is from 10.1.10.97 (Your MacOS host), and that is why B can return that traffic to A, because it is actually sending it to the host and Virtualbox is translating the destination address to the NAT'd virtual machine.

You have two alternatives:

1. Change the adapter type to Bridged (This will change the IP address on the Ubuntu machine but is also the easiest if you have little networking knowledge).
2. Forward a port in the host to the machine A (I see this as the most suitable solution without changing the architecture)

For case 1 is as easy as change the settings in Virtualbox and then get the new IP.

For case 2, what you should do is go to the Machine Settings, in the network section, expand Advanced and set a port forwarding, for instance:

[image: Port forwarding rules]

In this way, from computer B you will be able to wget from the host IP (NOT the 10.0.2.15, the 10.1.10.97) on port 8080, and this traffic will be forwarded (Destination NAT'd) to 10.0.2.15 using: `wget http://10.1.10.97:8080/path/in/ubuntu`

You will never be able to point directly from 10.1.10.216 to 10.0.2.15 as machine B has no routes to 10.0.2.15

I recommend you read a little bit about NAT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

There's a lot of assumings in this answer, I hope it helps.